# My jtable doesn´t sort my integer numbers correctly

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

When I´m click the top of the column to sort the numbers they doesn´t sort correctly. Example:
-89
-50
-100
And when I sort these numbers, they go like:
-100
-50
-89

My code to show my table and sort it is:

```
public void showTable() {
        String matrix[][] = new String[list.size()][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            matrix[i][0] = list.get(i).getCodigo();
            matrix[i][1] = list.get(i).getNombre();
            matrix[i][2] = list.get(i).getCarrera();
            matrix[i][3] = list.get(i).getSemestre();
            matrix[i][4] = list.get(i).getPromedio();
        }

        jtStudents.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(matrix, new String [] {"Codigo", "Nombre", "Carrera", "Semestre", "Promedio"}));

        tm = new DefaultTableModel(matrix, new String [] {"Codigo", "Nombre", "Carrera", "Semestre", "Promedio"}){
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                Class Value;
                if (column >= 0 && column < getColumnCount()) {
                    Value = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
                } else {
                    Value = Object.class;
                }
                return Value;
            }
        };


        jtStudents.setModel(tm);
        tableSorted = new TableRowSorter<>(jtStudents.getModel());
        jtStudents.setRowSorter(tableSorted);
    }
```

Comment: You don't have any number in your table model. Only Strings. Put actual integers in your model. And override getColumnClass() in your table model to return Integer.class for the column containing those Integers.

Comment: That really help me, thanks